# Order a list in MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm

How can you order a list?

I'm using this, but it doesn't order.

In my ViewModel:

```
    private ObservableCollection<Person> _PersonList;
    public ObservableCollection<Person> PersonList
    {
        get
        {
            return _PersonList;
        }
        set
        {
            _PersonList = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("PersonList");
        }
    }
```

Here I fill the PersonList:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Person> GetPersons()
    {
        var persons = _IPersonDataService.GetPersons();
        ObservableCollection<Person> personList = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

        foreach(Person person in persons)
        {
            personList.Add(person);
        }

        return personList;
    }
```

Here is my View.xaml:

```
 <GridViewColumnHeader Command="{Binding SortOnIDCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
                                          Cursor="Hand">
```

The command works, when I insert a breakpoint it stops in the command.

```
    public RelayCommand SortOnIDCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
                PersonList.OrderBy(o => o.ID); 
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: PersonList = PersonList.OrderBy(o => o.ID);

Comment: @DanielTshuva no I tried that before

Answer (score 0):

`OrderBy` doesn't sort in place. It returns a sorted IEnumerable, that you aren't using.

Comment: Ye, but PersonList = PersonList.OrderBy(o => o.ID); won't work eather

Answer (score 0):

PersonList = new ObservableCollection(PersonList.OrderBy(o => o.ID));

Did the trick.